# how to get a short valid url

Tags: url

example url:

```
view.php?theme=1&id=5
```

On some blogs I see the following

```
view/1/5
```

or - `view.php/1/5`

I suppose once the above url is in address bar, the common way to get `theme` and `id` variable is using php `explode` function, but how to get this as a valid address.

If I write `<a href = 'view/1/5'></a>` - this is not a valid href.

Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement rewriteRule in your **.htaccess** file in the directory where your php files resides.

Something like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ view.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ view.php?id=$1
```

On your php you will have something like

```
<a href = "view/$id'></a>
```

or

```
<a href = "/$id'></a>
```

Always remember to shut down apachae and restart it for it to take effect